# Facebook api - get a post stats from my app wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using javascript and want to get a Facebook post stats eg views, likes, comments and shares for that one post.

I want to get the post by post name eg name of post could be: job Manchester

This post would only come from my company wall that I have permission to.

I am open to suggestions.

I've no attempt to show, I can't seem to find a solution in the Facebook api developer docs.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “post name” in the API.

Comment: How could a get a specific post ? I'm guessing by an I'd maybe? CBroe

Comment: Yes, of course. // Go check the documentation for the Post object and for post insights to see which fields/metrics are available.